# Drools add rules from another project into kmodule?

Tags: java, drools

So the docs state that you can load kie modules programatically with

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

KieContainer kieContainer = newKieContainer(ks.newReleaseId("my.org","my.artifact.id","version"));
KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("ktest");
```

Is there a way to do that through `maven` and the `kmodule.xml`?
My use case would be to use the rules I wrote in this project, in another project and add onto them. Maybe I missed it in the 7.7 docs, if so please link and I'll set an appointment with my eye doctor.

Addendum: 
I imagine the `kmodule.xml` to look similar to this:

```
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
<configuration>
</configuration>
<!-- Shared Knowledgebase -->
<kbase name="am" packages="my.package.name, rules">  
    <ksession name="default" type="stateful" default="true"/>
</kbase>
```

However that does not seem to see the package

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did figure this out. I thought it had something to do with `package` in the `kmodule.xml`. But in actuality it was simply adding the `incluldes = "package.name"` and it figured it out all on its own.

However, I also recommend @Prog_G answer as well, though it was not what I was looking for, I'm sure it will help others with this same question.

final result:

```
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
<configuration>
</configuration>
<kbase name="am" packages="rules" includes = "my.package.name">  
    <ksession name="default" type="stateful" default="true"/>
</kbase>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a different Drools project in another Project. Follow the following steps:

1. Build the Drool project that you want to use in the other Drool Project. Before building properly check the `kmodule.xml` file.
2. After building the project use `mvn file upload` command to upload the jar into the `local maven repository` i.e `.m2 repository`. Example - `mvn install:install-file -Dfile="pathToJAr" -DgroupId="groupId" -DartifactId="artifactId" -Dversion="version" -Dpackaging="jar"`. You can use your custom groupId,artifactId, and version.
3. Then add the above custom groupId,artifactId and version in the `pom.xml` as a dependency.
4. Then create `kieConatiner`and kieSession like follow:

   `KieServices.Factory.get();
   ReleaseId rs= ks.newReleaseId("artifactId","groupId","version");
   KieContainer kieContainer = ks.newKieContainer(rs);
   KieScanner kieScanner = ks.newKieScanner(kieContainer);
   kieScanner.start(10000);`

KieScanner is used to dynamically update the `KieContainer`. Here `kieScanner` will scan the local maven repo every 10 sec.

Comment: Sort of. I was hoping for something that uses the kmodule to point to another project's kbase to be able to use the rules. I think I found the documentation for it [here](http://planet.jboss.org/post/configuration_and_convention_based_building_and_utilization) I'm will try this and get back as an answer